# SetParent(winapi) returns access denied

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, winapi

We're inside WPF window, starting new process with GUI window. Then call SetParent() to move newly created window into MainWindow. When running as administrator, everything goes correct, but if launch program as user (who actually is system administrator), SetParent() fails with GetLastError()==5 (access denied).

I've tried raising privileges of current process (AdjustTokenPrivileges), to no avail.

Any ideas why SetParent could fail, and how can I fix it?

Code:

```
process = new Process();
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "some_gui_process.exe";
process.Start();
process.WaitForInputIdle();
var hChildWindow = process.MainWindowHandle;
var hParentWindow = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
SetParent(hChildWindow, hParentWindow);
```

Comment: sounds like you're into User Access Control issue (UAC). you can specify that your program needs elevated privileges, or you can use COM to call into an elevated out-of-process server (it's a special COM interface thing, I don't recall the details). However, instead of moving one process' window into another process' window, just *communicate* with the new process and display its info. COM is a great way to communicate with another process. Windows mailslots ain't bad either (used internally by DCOM, I seem to recall).

Comment: It is [technically legal to juggle chainsaws](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx), but you need to understand the consequences before breaking the rules.

Comment: As @IInspectable says, you *can* do what you're asking, but it's a **REALLY BAD IDEA**.  Unless *both* apps are expecting to run with merged input queues, you're going to have an unending stream of problems.